# Video not displaying on tiktok clone

Tags: reactjs, video, onclick, use-ref

I'm trying to display and play the video but nothing shows up on the screen, is there anything wrong with my function or my codes? Can anybody help me? Thank you so much!

```
    import React, { useRef } from "react";
    import "./Video.css";
    
    function Video() {
      const videoRef = useRef(null);
    
      const onVideoPress = () => {
        videoRef.current.play();
      };
      return (
        <div className="video">
          <video height="500px" width="300px" onClick={onVideoPress} ref={videoRef}>
            <source src="./video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          </video>{" "}
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default Video;
```

This is my App.js:

```
    import React from "react";
    import Video from "./Video";
    import "./App.css";
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <>
          hello code{" "}
          <div className="app">
            <div className="app-videos">
              <Video />
              <Video />
              <Video />
              <Video />
            </div>{" "}
          </div>{" "}
        </>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

This is my directory:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keB0h.png)

Comment: please share how your directory is structured

Comment: i've just add the directory picture in my post. Please check!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 import Video from './video.mp4';
....
  <video height="500px" width="300px" onClick={onVideoPress} ref={videoRef} controls>
     <source src={Video} type="video/mp4" />
 </video>
```

instead of doing this

```
<video height="500px" width="300px" onClick={onVideoPress} ref={videoRef}>
     <source src="./video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 </video>
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you've created your project via `create-react-app`, then you will want to create a `Videos` folder under the public directory, and put your video files there. **not in the `src` folder**.

So put your video file in `TIKTOK-clone/public/Videos/video1.mp4`. Then clear your browser cache, rebuild, and reload app.

**NOTE:** make sure you import video files as such:

`<source src="/Videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>`